# Approach to apply canny edge detector on a video instead of a still image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, video-processing, edge-detection

As part of my current project, I need to perform edge detection using canny edge detector on a given video. I know how to do this on a still image. But, Iam interetsed to know if there is any other approach to do this on a video instead of simply applying canny over all the frames one after the other.

- Iam adding the sample code for edge detector using canny on a still
  image.
- I tried the same approach over a video by reading all the frames one
  by one and I got the output as well.
- I am actually interested to know is this the only approach to be
  followed incase of a video or is there any other approach for a video.

```
    #reading a still image
    image = cv2.imread(image_path)

    #converting to Grayscale
    gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    #applying gaussian low pass filter
    gauss_image = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray_image, kernel_size,sigmaX,sigmaY)

    #applying canny edge detector
    edges = cv2.Canny(gauss_image,lower_threshold, upper_threshold)
```

Comment: How could there be another approach? A video is literally a collection of frames.

Comment: With this can I conclude that Video analysis is nothing but 'N' times of Image analysis where N is number of frames in a video.

Comment: That's a valid conclusion, although video analysis is generally about what you do to combine the individual image analyses.

Comment: Alright, thank you.

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish for this video? There's a lot more that you can do with a video vs. independent images. The sequential nature of it gives you extra power to track and segment objects.

Comment: I have a video in which a person will be displaying hand gestures. So, my goal is to apply canny and get the region of interest (i.e hand and head part of that person). At present what I am doing is, reading the video frame by frame and applying canny over each and every frame. Now, I am curious to know the other possible approaches which could actually be able to perform this task.

Comment: well, the video will at least let you track the regions of interest. If you set them once, you can keep them centered on the head and hand so long as neither moves too fast from frame to frame. Beyond that it won't help much with gesture recognition though.

Comment: Do you mean to say that using canny won't help in gesture recognition? Canny is a part of the segmentation phase in my project. In addition to this DWT will also be used to further generate the true edges in the frame. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Are you trying to speed-up your application?

Comment: Assuming that such a possibility exists (such as filtering in the DCT space) and that you can obtain a "Canny edge" video without decompressing the frames. What use would that be ? Don't you need to process those frame anyway ?